# Unknown column 'result' in 'field list'

Tags: database, list, phpmyadmin, field

I have a website. With forecasts of sport. When in admin panel want to add new forecasts released the following error:

error!
There was a problem saving the tips: DB Error: Unknown column 'result' in 'field list'

Where is perhaps the error in the system? Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: You should share much more info about the operation you are doing

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $tips_open = $this->settings_lib->item('tips.allow_post');
?>

<?php

if (validation_errors()) :
?>
<div class='alert alert-block alert-error animated animated-short zoomIn'>
    <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a>
    <h4 class='alert-heading'>
        <?php echo lang('tips_errors_message'); ?>
    </h4>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
<?php
endif;

$id = isset($tips->id) ? $tips->id : '';

?>


    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">                  

            <p class="text-center"><h4><?php if (isset($toolbar_title)) : ?><?php echo $toolbar_title; ?><?php endif; ?>
                <span class="pull-right fs12"><span class="hidden-xs"><?php echo lang('tips_action_before_post');?></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue ml20" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TipsRules">
                    <?php echo lang('tips_action_read_rules');?>
                </button></span>
            </h4></p>
            <div class="divider-4"></div>

            <?php if ( $tips_open ) { ?>

                <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(), 'id="form" class="form-horizontal"'); ?>

                    <?php if (isset($current_user->id)) : ?>
                      <input id="created_by" type="hidden" name="created_by" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $current_user->id; ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <input id="created_on" type="hidden" name="created_on"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" />


                    <!-- Start Row -->
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group<?php echo form_error('sport_id') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">

                                <?php echo form_label(lang('tips_select_sport') . lang('bf_form_label_required'), 'sport_id', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
                                <select name="sport_id" id="sport_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value=""><?php echo lang('tips_select_sport');?></option>
                                    <?php foreach ($sports->result() as $row) {
                                        $sel = ($row->id==set_value('sport_id'))?'selected="selected"':'';
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo $row->name;?></option>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </select>
                                <span class='help-block'><?php echo form_error('sport_id'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="league">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group<?php echo form_error('league_id') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <label class="control-label"><?php echo lang('tips_select_league');?></label>
                                    <select name="league_id" id="league_id" class="form-control">
                                        <!-- Auto Populated --> 
                                    </select>
                                    <?php echo form_error('league_id');?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Row -->


                    <!-- Start Row -->
                    <div class="row">


                        <div class="match">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="form-group<?php echo form_error('match_id') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <?php echo form_label(lang('tips_select_event') . lang('bf_form_label_required'), 'match_id', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
                                    <select name="match_id" id="match_id" class="form-control">
                                        <!-- Auto Populated -->     
                                    </select>
                                    <?php echo form_error('match_id');?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <!-- End Row -->    

                    <!-- Start Row -->
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="bet_id">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group<?php echo form_error('bet_id') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <?php echo form_label(lang('tips_bet_category') . lang('bf_form_label_required'), 'bet_id', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>

                                    <select name="bet_id" id="bet_id" class="form-control">
                                        <!-- Auto Populated --> 
                                    </select>

                                    <?php echo form_error('bet_id');?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="choice_id">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <div class="form-group<?php echo form_error('choice_id') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <?php echo form_label(lang('tips_bet_type') . lang('bf_form_label_required'), 'choice_id', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>

                                    <select name="choice_id" id="choice_id" class="form-control">
                                        <!-- Auto Populated -->     
                                    </select>
                                    <?php echo form_error('choice_id');?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="stake">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo form_error('stake') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <?php echo form_label(lang('tips_stake') . lang('bf_form_label_required'), 'stake', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
                                    <?php $stakes = array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3','4'=>'4','5'=>'5','6'=>'6','7'=>'7','8'=>'8','9'=>'9','10'=>'10');?>
                                    <select name="stake" id="stake" class="form-control">
                                        <option value=""><?php echo lang('tips_select_stake');?></option>
                                        <?php foreach ($stakes as $stake) {
                                            $sel = ($stake==set_value('stake'))?'selected="selected"':'';
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $stake;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo $stake;?></option>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </select>
                                    <span class='help-block'><?php echo form_error('stake'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>          


                    </div>
                    <!-- End Row -->    

                    <input type="hidden" name="odds" id="odds" value="" />

                    <!-- Start Row -->
                    <div class="row">               

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group<?php echo form_error('description') ? ' has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <?php echo form_label(lang('tips_description') . lang('bf_form_label_required'), 'description', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
                                <textarea class="textarea" name="description" id="description" placeholder="<?php echo lang('tips_min_words');?>" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <span class='help-block'><?php echo form_error('description'); ?></span>
                        </div>                  

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Row -->    



                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <input type='submit' name='save' class='btn btn-blue' value="<?php echo lang('tips_action_send'); ?>" />    
                    </div>

                <?php echo form_close(); ?>

                <?php } else { ?>

                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <h4> Sorry!</h4>
                        Cannot bet now.
                    </div>

                <?php } ?>

        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->



    <div id="TipsRules" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content p10">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo lang('tips_rules'); ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" data-ng-controller="rulesCtrl">


                    <?php $rules = $this->settings_lib->item('tips.rules');

                    echo $rules
                    ;?>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer bg-default">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/modal-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Define site_url variable for use in the js file
        var site_url = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
        // Define error messages for jquery validation

        var description_forgot = '<?php echo lang('tips_desc_forgot');?>'
        var description_req = '<?php echo lang('tips_min_words');?>'

    </script>
```